# I installed Micorosoft Sbom-tool, but it cannot detect any packages

Tags: package, nuget, package-managers

I installed and ran sbom-tool in Linux and Windows environments, but it didn't seem to detect a single package like bellow.
Is there something I am missing?

```
[INFO] Log file: XXXX.log
[INFO] Run correlation id: XXX

[INFO] Attempting to load default detectors
[INFO] 20 detectors were found in Microsoft.ComponentDetection.Detectors

[WARN] Provided search path XXX/Plugins does not exist.


[INFO] Finding components...
[INFO] Starting enumeration of XXX
[INFO] No instructions received to scan docker images.
[INFO] Enumerated 388 files and 80 directories in 00:00:00.0409279
[WARN] SPDX file at XXX/manifest.spdx.json does not have root elements in documentDescribes section, considering SPDXRef-Document as a root element.
[INFO]
[INFO] _______________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
[INFO] |Component Detector Id         |Detection Time                |# Components Found            |# Explicitly Referenced                 |
[INFO] |______________________________|______________________________|______________________________|________________________________________|
[INFO] |CocoaPods                     |0.088 seconds                 |0                             |0
                     |
[INFO] |______________________________|______________________________|______________________________|________________________________________|
[INFO] |Go                            |0.088 seconds                 |0                             |0
                     |
[INFO] |______________________________|______________________________|______________________________|________________________________________|
[INFO] |Gradle                        |0.088 seconds                 |0                             |0
                     |
[INFO] |______________________________|______________________________|______________________________|________________________________________|
[INFO] |Ivy (Beta)                    |0.15 seconds                  |0                             |0
                     |
[INFO] |______________________________|______________________________|______________________________|________________________________________|
[INFO] |Linux                         |0.047 seconds                 |0                             |0
                     |
[INFO] |______________________________|______________________________|______________________________|________________________________________|
[INFO] |MvnCli                        |0.15 seconds                  |0                             |0
                     |
[INFO] |______________________________|______________________________|______________________________|________________________________________|
[INFO] |Npm                           |0.088 seconds                 |0                             |0
                     |
[INFO] |______________________________|______________________________|______________________________|________________________________________|
[INFO] |NpmWithRoots                  |0.088 seconds                 |0                             |0
                     |
[INFO] |______________________________|______________________________|______________________________|________________________________________|
[INFO] |NuGet                         |0.089 seconds                 |0                             |0
                     |
[INFO] |______________________________|______________________________|______________________________|________________________________________|
[INFO] |NuGetPackagesConfig (Beta)    |0.088 seconds                 |0                             |0
                     |
[INFO] |______________________________|______________________________|______________________________|________________________________________|
[INFO] |NuGetProjectCentric           |0.092 seconds                 |0                             |0
                     |
[INFO] |______________________________|______________________________|______________________________|________________________________________|
[INFO] |Pip                           |0.088 seconds                 |0                             |0
                     |
[INFO] |______________________________|______________________________|______________________________|________________________________________|
[INFO] |Pnpm                          |0.088 seconds                 |0                             |0
                     |
[INFO] |______________________________|______________________________|______________________________|________________________________________|
[INFO] |Poetry (Beta)                 |0.089 seconds                 |0                             |0
                     |
[INFO] |______________________________|______________________________|______________________________|________________________________________|
[INFO] |Ruby                          |0.088 seconds                 |0                             |0
                     |
[INFO] |______________________________|______________________________|______________________________|________________________________________|
[INFO] |RustCrateDetector             |0.088 seconds                 |0                             |0
                     |
[INFO] |______________________________|______________________________|______________________________|________________________________________|
[INFO] |SPDX22SBOM                    |0.13 seconds                  |1                             |0
                     |
[INFO] |______________________________|______________________________|______________________________|________________________________________|
[INFO] |Vcpkg (Beta)                  |0.089 seconds                 |0                             |0
                     |
[INFO] |______________________________|______________________________|______________________________|________________________________________|
[INFO] |Yarn                          |0.091 seconds                 |0                             |0
                     |
[INFO] |______________________________|______________________________|______________________________|________________________________________|
[INFO] |Total                         |0.17 seconds                  |1                             |0
                     |
[INFO] |______________________________|______________________________|______________________________|________________________________________|
[INFO]
```

I tried to generate an SBOM from the sbom-tool source code as follows

[Linux environment]

1. obtained the Linux executable as described in the [readme](https://github.com/microsoft/sbom-tool#linux-curl)
2. obtained and extracted the [sbom-tool source code](https://github.com/microsoft/sbom-tool/releases/tag/v0.3.1).
3. executed the command

```
. /sbom-tool generate -b <output path> -bc <source path> -pn TestProject -pv 1.0.0 -ps MyCompany -nsb http://mycompany.com
```

[Windows environment].

1. download the [executable file for windows](https://github.com/microsoft/sbom-tool/releases/tag/v0.3.1)
2. obtained and extracted the [sbom-tool source code](https://github.com/microsoft/sbom-tool/releases/tag/v0.3.1)
3. executed the command

```
sbom-tool-win-x64.exe generate -b <output path> -bc <source path> -pn TestProject -pv 1.0.0 -ps MyCompany -nsb http://mycompany.com
```